# Unable to submit website with HSTS for preload

Tags: http, ssl, https, http-headers, hsts

We have currently implemented HSTS into our website. However when I want to submit it on hstspreload.org I get this error:

> Response error: No HSTS header is present on the response.

When I visit the site ([Link here](http://digichef.cz)) I normally get HSTS response header. What could possibly cause this?

Comment: *"When I visit the site (... link ...) I normally get HSTS response header."* - I don't get this header either, no matter if I use  curl or a browser. Thus `hstspreload.org` is correct. I have no idea how you've checked for the header which you claim gets send.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that is weird. 10 minutes ago, I got the HSTS response header. Now I don't get it as well...